# DatePicker not setting Year unless dropdown is changed explicitly when original Year is outside dropdown range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have set up a JQuery DatePicker with the following code:

```
       $('input[data-type="calendar"]').each(function ()
        {
            $(this).datepicker(
            {

                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                yearRange: "-1:+10",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonText: "Select date",
                showOn: "both",
                buttonImage: "../Images/calendar.jpg",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                setDate: "-0d",
                defaultDate: 0
            });
        });
```

The problem with this is that if the original date in the datepicker has a Year that is outside the range of the Year dropdown (2020-2031) then if I only change the date using the Calendar the Year does not change to the default Dropdown Year (2020).

Example: Date in textbox is 01/01/1900

I open the calendar. The Month drodown displays "Jan" and the Year dropdown displays "2020".

I don't change either of them. Instead I change the date to the 15th of the month.

What I want: Date to be 01/15/2020

What actually displays: 01/15/1900

What do I need to do to have the date use the current value in the dropdown without me having to change the year to some other year and back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to replicate the issue as you described it. Consider the following example I constructed.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[data-type="calendar"]').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      yearRange: "-1:+10",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      setDate: "-0d",
      defaultDate: 0,
      minDate: "01/01/2020",
      maxDate: "12/31/2030"
    });
    $(el).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Date 1: <input type="text" id="datepicker-1" data-type="calendar" /></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Date 2: <input type="text" id="datepicker-2" data-type="calendar" /></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Date 3: <input type="text" id="datepicker-3" data-type="calendar" /></p>
</div>
```

All dates show today, `03/31/2021`.

This will use the Date from the browser. The Browser gets the date from the OS. You may need to ensure that Date and Time are configured correctly on your test device.

**Update**

To constrict the Range further, you want to add `minDate` and `maxDate` options.

> A string in the format defined by the `dateFormat` option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven days from today.

If the User manually enters a date, and then clicks a date in the UI, it will return the the proper Year.

```
  minDate: "01/01/2020",
  maxDate: "12/31/2030"
```

Comment: Manually write in the date 01/01/1900 into any of your text boxes. Then click out of it so that the date is set. Now click back on the text box so that the Calendar appears. You will notice that the year dropdown shows 2020. Don't touch that dropdown - just click on one of the dates, e.g. the 18th. The date will now be set to 01/18/1900. In that exact scenario I want it to be set to 01/18/2020 instead. The only way to get that currently via the UI would be for me to change the year dropdown to a different year and then back to 2020 before clicking on a day.

Comment: @Sperick this does happen and I can see the issue happens for any year, E.G. 1900 or 2000. My first question is how often do expect a User to type in an incorrect Year (outside of 2020 and 2030)? Typing a date in manually is a Change; so will need a callback that can help prevent the User from entering a Date that is outside of the Range.

Comment: @Sperick Please see the Update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I should probably have specified that this is an Edit text box that has either "01/01/1900" or "12/31/999" loaded to it as default

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[data-type="calendar"]').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      yearRange: "-150:+0",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      setDate: "-0d",
      defaultDate: 0
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Date 1: <input type="text" id="datepicker-1" data-type="calendar" /></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Date 2: <input type="text" id="datepicker-2" data-type="calendar" /></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Date 3: <input type="text" id="datepicker-3" data-type="calendar" /></p>
</div>
```

Change the yearRange to yearRange: "-150:+0". So that's it.

Comment: The DatePickers I am using are different looking. They look like what @Twisty has in his answer. It must be the version of the framework since our code snippets are the exact same. Have a look at my response to his answer. I need to keep the look of them the same as they are currently so I cannot go with what you have